# Intel HD 520 really weak performance | Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: lenovo, performance, intel

Using Lenovo e460 with i5-6200u + Intel HD 520.

Performance is terrible, 20FPS on games I got 80+ in Windows (same settings) and even native linux games like CSGO.

I've done all the updates etc, does anyone know if I should be using different drivers and how?

Answer (score 1):

I have HP Probook 450 G3 with the same CPU & GPU.
Also see that preformance of our integrated GPU is qutie low.

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS sometimes GPU was stuck. As I read that skylake architecture fully supported only with kernel 4.3 and newer.

Then I was installed Ubuntu 15.10 and also installed from this link http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ latest kernel (4.5-rc6-wily). And fullHD video I see without something problem, glxgear test has 60-70 fps.

Also you can try to install https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads the latest open intel VGA drivers. May be this help you to increase preformance in gaming.

But I'm sure that firstly you need to install Ubuntu 15.10 because it has newer version of mesa drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I recently purchased a secondhand ThinkPad T470 (with an Intel HD 520 and i5-6300u), and the desktop performance on Kubuntu 18.04 "feels" a lot more sluggish (and jittery) than my T450s (with the Intel 5500 iGPU and the i5-5200u).

It is very noticeable when scrolling on a web page full of images, or scrolling in an list on an Android Virtual Device. When I compare the difference with my T450s, it makes my T470 appear sluggish and jittery.